# Needless needles

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has tags [butterfly-needle](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/butterfly-needle), [needles-cannula](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needles-cannula) and [paresthesia-pins-needles](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paresthesia-pins-needles). Too many needles.

1. Should cannulas and needles be under the same tag? If so, why not have tag [needles](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needles) with [cannulas](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cannulas) as a synonym? Either both singular or both plural, please. I prefer both plural, but that is obviously a matter of personal taste.
2. Are butterfly needles special enough to deserve a tag? Should they be under, say, [needles](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needles)?
3. Colloquially, paresthesia may be known as "pins and needles", but this introduces the risk of mistagging. I propose that [paresthesia-pins-needles](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paresthesia-pins-needles) be renamed [paresthesia](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paresthesia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created [needles](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needles) and renamed [butterfly-needle](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/butterfly-needle) to simply [needles](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/needles) because I don't think there's anything special about butterfly needles that warrants a separate tag.

Renamed [paresthesia-pins-needles](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paresthesia-pins-needles) to [paresthesia](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paresthesia).

Did not make [cannula](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cannula) a synonym because cannulas can be of several types, many of which don't involve needles. There is currently no [cannula](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cannula).